# MariaDB with SSL auth: can't connect using R (working connection within terminal)

Tags: r, ssl, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to a remote MariaDB database through R using SSL authentication, but keep failing.

I can connect directly from the terminal using `mysql -u -p -P -h --ssl-ca --ssl-key --ssl-cert --ssl-capath --ssl-cipher`, so the certificate is valid and the connection is working.

In R, I'm trying to connect using two drivers, giving me two different errors:

- using RMariaDB: `Error: Failed to connect: SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)`
- using RMySQL: `Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 'myUsername'@'myHostIP' (using password: YES)`

I am providing the full path for the certificate files (same as the ones used with the working connection in the terminal), there is no issue with the permissions of these files.

I tried a fresh R install, a fresh MySQL/MariaDB install, downgrading RMariaDB, etc... and nothing has helped yet.

I also tried to set up odbc on Ubuntu, but did not succeed... However, I'm sure I can connect using straight RMariaDB and this is the solution I would prefer.

Here's my sessionInfo() output:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8      
 [8] LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RJDBC_0.2-7.1  rJava_0.9-11   RMySQL_0.10.19 DBI_1.1.0      RMariaDB_1.0.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_1.1-15.2    compiler_3.6.3  hms_0.5.3       DBI_1.1.0       tools_3.6.3     Rcpp_1.0.3      bit64_0.9-7     vctrs_0.2.2     RMySQL_0.10.19  pkgconfig_2.0.3 rlang_0.4.4
```

Any hint?

Comment: Looks like this happens on MacOS?

Comment: I didnt specify that I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 (4.15.0-1073-oem)
MySQL version: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB

Comment: Updating some RMariaDB dependencies using devtools solved it. Closing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a version issue between the RMariaDB package and some of its dependencies.
Updating all dependencies using devtools solved the problem.